# How does one replicate the "windows XP style" theme on Windows 7?

Tags: windows

I have gone ahead and selected the Windows Classic theme in WIN7's "Window Color and Appearance" to turn off Aero.

I'm looking to replicate the "windows XP style" theme to get a screen recognition program "feel at home" since the objects its looking for were on an XP machine.

Is it possible to edit/import the "windows XP style" theme file and use it in WIN7?

I am mostly looking to get the colors/fonts similar. Windows/buttons would be good too.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see if Classic Shell would work for you at  http://sourceforge.net/projects/classicshell/.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few tweaks you can make such as disbaling program groups and showing program names and icons in the taskbar. To get the old XP-style classic start menu back you will have to install a little program; you can search for windows 7 classic menu on google.

Unfortunately, I'm on my work computer which is on XP otherwise I could use my personal laptop to tell you the exact steps.

Try looking on lifehacker.com for windows 7 tagged questions, some good tips there.

It might also be worth getting on contact with the company and see if they have a un updated version for windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the [Luna](http://www.askvg.com/download-windows-xp-luna-theme-for-windows-7/) theme, which is a Windows 7 theme that emulates the look and feel of Windows XP. The fonts may not be perfect, but you can always tweak those manually.

Comment: Also, the Luna theme uses the classic blue Windows XP style. If you prefer the silver Windows XP style, then you might want to use Silver Luna instead: http://www.askvg.com/download-windows-xp-luna-silver-theme-for-windows-7/